# Compilation issue on new kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have installed Fedora 22 , which has default kernel 4.0.4.
But I have a requirement of Kernel 4.1.4, so I installed kernel 4.1.4 on Fedora 22. and make an entry in grub for new kernel.

Kernel 4.1.4 is installed successfully and I am able to login with new kernel.

output of "uname -a"-

```
uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.1.4 #1 SMP Fri Aug 7 10:52:36 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Path of new kernel -

```
/usr/src/linux-4.1.4
```

Path of include folder -

```
/usr/src/linux-4.1.4/include
```

Now I wrote a C program, which uses the macro AF_MPLS, which is defined in new kernel headers. Compilation of c program is failed because AF_MPLS is not in /usr/include/sys/socket.h.

Error found -

```
RouteMPLS.c: In function âroute_addâ:
RouteMPLS.c:212:24: error: âAF_MPLSâ undeclared (first use in this function)
req.r.rtm_family = AF_MPLS;
```

Headers file used in RouteMPLS.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

So, I changed the location of header file a/c to new kernel-

```
#include "/usr/src/linux-4.1.4/include/linux/socket.h"
```

still it throws an compilation error, then I tried with

```
gcc RouteMPLS.c -I /usr/src/linux-4.1.4/include/
In file included from /usr/src/linux-4.1.4/include/linux/kernel.h:6:0,
             from /usr/src/linux-4.1.4/include/linux/skbuff.h:17,
             from /usr/src/linux-4.1.4/include/linux/netlink.h:6,
             from RouteMPLS.c:3:
/usr/src/linux-4.1.4/include/linux/linkage.h:7:25: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
```

compilation terminated.

Please guide how can I install our c program with new kernel headers -

Default kernel header location -

```
/usr/include
```

New Kernel header location -

```
/usr/src/linux-4.1.4/include
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to install the kernel headers?

Comment: I installed the new kernel-4.1.4 from source code -

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Installing the headers is a discrete step.

Comment: Do I need to install the kernel header separately ?

Comment: What does your kernel compilation tutorial say?

Comment: I follow some steps - 1. Download the kernel code. 2. Do make menuconfig. 3. make 4. make modules. 5 make modules_install 6. make install 7. Do grub changes

Comment: Then your tutorial isn't complete. It forgot the part about installing the headers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling using gcc with kernel header files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113959/compiling-using-gcc-with-kernel-header-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have the linux kernel 4.1.4 header files in the directory for kernel compilation.

To compile user programs, the compiler normally looks for them in `/usr/include` (well, in the new architectures, it is some more complicated) and there's normally a copy of the kernel headers for the running kernel installed inside `/usr/include`

But now, you have a kernel headers version mismatch.  You don't say where have you downloaded that sources from, but in the `Documentation` subdirectory of the kernel source tree, you have some document explaining how to install the kernel headers in the proper place, so the compiler for system applications finds them right.

Read the doc at `/usr/src/linux-4.1.4/Documentation` for a file which explainst how to install the kernel headers in the proper place.  Mainly, it refers to all files installed under `/usr/include/linux`, `/usr/include/asm` and (as is your case) `/usr/include/asm-amd64`.

### Note:

After some search in the kernel source tree, I have found a target `headers_install` in the Makefile (by trying `make help`) I suppose serves to install the header files from the kernel tree to the proper place.

So, the most probable way to install the kernel header files is to do:

```
make headers_install
```

or (in case you must install them in other place)

```
INSTALL_HDR_PATH=<new_path> make headers_install
```

(it says by default installation goes to `./usr`)